# C++ Incomplete class type pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers

In a source file I have 2 class definitions

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int * GetPtr(){
        return Obj;
    }

    int * Obj;
}

class Bar
{
public:
    ...

    std::vector<Foo> FooVector;
}
```

And in the same source file I have this function

```
void DoSomething()
{
    Bar* barVar = CreateBar(); // Returns pointer to class object
    Foo* fooVar = &barVar->FooVector[0]; 

    if (fooVar->GetPtr()) // Error here
        ...
}
```

Trying to compile this, I get the error "Pointer to incomplete class type not allowed" but the class is defined a few lines above it.

Comment: Please paste exact error message. `Foo* fooVar = &barVar->FooVector[0]; ` is wrong, use `Foo* fooVar = bar && !barVar->FooVector.empty() ? &barVar->FooVector[0] : nullptr; `. Put semicolons after `class`. Post real code.

Comment: In the process of producing an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you would likely solve the problem yourself, but if not at least you would have the bare minimum we need to assist you.

Comment: Is `Obj` really `int *` type?

Comment: Error is out of there, try to show minimal code reproduces the problem.

Comment: It seems as though I oversimplified the code. Where there is the int *Obj, it is actually a class aswell EntityBase Obj, defined in Base.h. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @KristapsKakstins that can be.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by properly implementing the classes.